# minimal N to reject the hypothesis of sharpe ratio

Tags: probability

> A strategy assumes to have an annual sharp ratio of 8. Now backtest on N days trading data. If the N days return is negative, how many days does N need to reject the assumption that the annual sharp ratio is equal to 8? We suppose 250 trading day annually.

Here is my answer:

Assume the annual return is $R,$ and the annual std is 1, then the null hypothesis is:

$$H_0: \text{sharpe ratio} = R \geq 8.$$
we denote $N$ days return is $R_N,$ then we have

$$\dfrac{R_N\times\dfrac{250}{N} - R}{1}\sim Z \Rightarrow R = R_N\times\dfrac{250}{N} - Z$$

Here $Z$ is standard normal. Assume the 95% confidential interval, we have

$$P\Big(R_N\times\dfrac{250}{N} - Z\geq 8\Big)\geq 95\%$$
$$\Rightarrow R_N\times\dfrac{250}{N} - 8 \geq \alpha_{95\%}.$$

It seems contradict to the negative $R_N.$

Comment: Is the volatility assumed to be known?

Comment: @Snoop for my understanding since it is a simple interview question, we always regard vol = 1 to get the value of mean. On the other hand, you have no more information to get the unknown vol.

Comment: Do you mean sharp**e** ratio?

Comment: @callculus42 yes, sorry for the typo